# Spring Web Socket call for Thread completion

Tags: spring, multithreading, websocket

I am working on a on Spring web service which calls a thread for a long running task, as I don't want to keep the user busy because the task can be really long.
I want to notify the user through web socket when the task on the thread has completed. What is the best procedure to do so in spring??

Answer (score 0):

Spring websocket can be used for this purpose. 
I beleive this would help you initially at least. https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/